# Windows XP PCs shut down using WMI command require mouse/keyboard input before completing shutdown

Tags: wmi, remote-shutdown

We use the WMI service to shut down PCs in our office remotely.

This works perfectly for our Windows 7 systems but we are finding that our Windows XP PCs get stuck in a "Shutting down" state indefinitely, after they receive the remote shutdown command.

The interesting thing is that, if a key is pressed on the keyboard of the offending PC or the mouse is nudged, the PC will continue to shut down and will be powered off within around 10 seconds.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Windows XP, Vista, 7, and 8 all come with a shutdown.exe for this type of thing (although the arguments/parameters changed after XP). 
On my Windows 8.1 system:

```
C:\Windows\System32>shutdown /?
Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e | /o] [/hybrid] [/f]

[/m \\computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
/?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
/i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
           This must be the first option.
/l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
/s         Shutdown the computer.
/r         Full shutdown and restart the computer.
/g         Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
           rebooted, restart any registered applications.
/a         Abort a system shutdown.
           This can only be used during the time-out period.
/p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
           Can be used with /d and /f options.
/h         Hibernate the local computer.
           Can be used with the /f option.
/hybrid    Performs a shutdown of the computer and prepares it for fast startup.
           Must be used with /s option.
/e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
/o         Go to the advanced boot options menu and restart the computer.
           Must be used with /r option.
/m \\computer Specify the target computer.
/t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
           The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
           If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
           implied.
/c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
           Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
/f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
           The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
           specified for the /t parameter.
/d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
           p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
           u indicates that the reason is user defined.
           If neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is
           unplanned.
           xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
           yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).
```

See http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000321.htm for a small tutorial on how to use some of these arguments/parameters.

EDIT:
I'm only mentioning it because maybe it won't display the same behavior.
As to what's causing the hang, it could be any number of programs running on those XP systems. I remember seeing some versions of Windows complain about waiting for a particular program to close before it would shut down, but I've never heard of an instance where the hang goes away after some keyboard/mouse activity.